# Create a conditional column on tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api, visualization

How would I create a conditional column on tableau which gives returns the following output on the input given below-

```
Type1       Type2       Type3    Desired output
ice-cream   null        null      ice-cream
crisps      candy     ice-cream   ice-cream
crisps      candy      candy      candy
ice-cream   crisps     null       crisps
```

I want to be able to filter the data based on this condition. Unfortunately I can't do this on SQL because a CTE massively increases the execution time on the server so I need create a parameter+ calculated field which does this.
Therefore the filter is taking the value in type 3 if it exists as the output
else it takes the value in type 2 and finally if type2 and 3 are null it takes value from type1

Answer (score 0):

The SQL expression:

```
select t.*, coalesce(type3, type2, type1) as desired
from t
```

should not noticeably increase the running time.  I can think of no database where adding such a calculation would change the execution plan -- with the exception of the single calculation on each row.

I don't see why a CTE would be needed.  You can also use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a business rule:

```
For the desired output column:
-- if the type3 column is not null return that.
-- otherwise if the type2 column is not null return that.
-- otherwise if the type3 column is not null return that
-- otherwise return null
```

---

You are not 100% clear on your business rules but it looks like

```
 COALESCE(type3,type2,type1)
```

will give the result you need.  This can be filtered on

Comment: Business rules?

Also need the answer on tableau not sql!!

Comment: @KFC1999 why do you have the SQL tag if you don't want SQL?  Do you not know what business rules means?  That means what is the logical rule that defines the output of the "Desired output" column

Comment: Ah this is not the actual data it's a sample df that I keep handy for SO questions

Comment: @KFC1999 -- I write an example of what my guess as to your business rule.  If it was something else then you should make that clear (since Gordan thought it was the same thing)

Comment: Will keep above in mind-usually I've been taught above as programming logic but thank you!

Comment: sure-- if you are programming for a business (as most of us do) then it is business rules.

Answer (score 0):

create a calculated field in Tableau with the following calculation

```
IF [TYPE3] <> 'null' THEN
[Type3] 
Elseif [Type2] <> 'null' THEN
[TYPE2] 
Else [type1]
End
```

Unfortunately tableau doesn't recognize 'null' as a separate datatype thus, the functions ifnull/isnull can't be used.